# On 14.04, my kernel version is 3.11.0-18?

Tags: kernel, 14.04, versions

After upgrading to 14.04, my kernel is not upgraded! it's like before:

`Linux Boxi 3.11.0-18-generic #32-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 18 21:11:14 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Here's what I did:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
sudo do-release-upgrade
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

---

`lsb_release -a`

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

Comment: please file a bug report - at least two questions have reported the same issue. The developers need to be aware of the situation and fix it for future users.  Thanks.

Comment: The same happened to me on upgrading from Ubuntu 15.04 to 15.10. The accepted answer solved the issue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just upgrade your kernel afterwards using apt-get.

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-generic
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need is

`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`

More more info check this question - [What is “dist-upgrade” and why does it upgrade more than “upgrade”?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/81585/what-is-dist-upgrade-and-why-does-it-upgrade-more-than-upgrade)

Comment: `do-release-upgrade` works based on `dist-upgrade`!