# Virtualbox didn't survive upgrade from 14.04 to 14.10

Tags: upgrade, virtualbox, 14.10

Normally, when I upgrade from one version of Ubuntu to another, my virtual box virtual machines survive the upgrade.

However, after upgrading from 14.04 to 14.10, they did not. I submitted a bug [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/virtualbox/+bug/1384885), which provides this [screenshot](http://neartalk.com/ss/2014-10-23_001_499x521.png).

Anyway, I'm not sure I understand how to get this back going again. I uninstalled virtual box and reinstalled it like this:

```
sudo apt-get remove virtualbox ; sudo apt-get install virtualbox
```

This didn't achieve anything. It seems like the fix is more involved than this. Please advise.

Comment: Probably unrelated. I wish I had a suggestion for you. You can try the update I added above; I don't see how it would hurt.

Comment: Can you please answer you own question with the solution stated in your question and remove it from there? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

***This answer is a self answer that the OP has posted as an "update" section in the question.***
(@LonnieBest If you post a real self answer, leave a comment on this, and I delete it.)

Thanks to this [post](https://askubuntu.com/a/451173/256054), I fixed this with the following command(s):

```
sudo apt-get update ; sudo apt-get install linux-generic
```

(took effect after reboot)

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. However my kernel was the current version. The resolution to my problem was to go to Virtual Box site and download and run in Virtual Box the current extension pack.

Comment: don't know why this answer got -1. the problem was in the extension pack, after it's removal/update everything works, thanks