# Upgrade from 12.04 to 14.04. Kernel not upgraded

Tags: 14.04, upgrade, kernel

I had upgraded a VPS server from 12.04 to 14.04, but recently noticed that that the kernel is 2.6.32. I am not an expert Linux user but unfortunately, it is my responsibility.

I have checked how to upgrade kernel, and it seems simple enough. Would appreciate if someone could give me advice on which kernel should I upgrade to (3.17?) and what are the things I should keep in mind while doing it?

Answer (score 1):

I found a link to a problem like this in another post:  I would stress that prior to attempting the upgrades, you should back up your data.

The post suggested that perhaps the `linux` meta-package had been removed, and that the solution is to re-install this package.

```
sudo apt-get install linux linux-generic
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

The [original answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/175397/283721) goes on to discuss that prior kernels will still be present on your system, and could be accessed through the grub menu.

Comment: is it sudo apt-get install linux linux-generic or sudo apt-get install linux-generic?

Comment: It could be either, so I included both.  I'm running 14.10 Gnome, and I have only `linux-generic` installed.  You should also check your grub to determine if grub is being asked to boot from a specific kernel:  `ls /boot/vm*` will show you the kernels installed in your boot area.

Comment: When I tried linux linux-generic I am getting unable to locate package linux. Installed with linx-generic. But after reboot, I am still seeing the old Kernel. It is an openVZ and I guess the kernel is shared. I got a feeling that I won't be able to upgrade the kernel. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: I don't have much experience with openVZ, so I'll kick off the thread here.  You should check your grub file, however, to make sure that it is not booting into the old kernel.

Comment: I get /usr/sbin/grub-probe: error: failed to get canonical path of '/vz/private/11087' when I run update-grub. Thanks for all your help, I will talk to VPS provider.