# Why my kernel is not the latest for 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, apt, upgrade, kernel

My kernel is currently

```
Linux scv 3.13.0-34-generic #60-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 13 15:45:27 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

But I know it should be

```
3.13.0-45-generic #74
```

Why is it *not* updated by default on my pc upon execution of

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Any idea? How can I fix this?

---

**EDIT:**

executing

```
ema@scv:~$ cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS \n \l
```

reports 14.04.2 apparently...

---

**EDIT2:**

on my other computer, with a fresher install of Ubuntu 14.04, I got *3.13.0-45-generic #74*...

---

**EDIT3:**

all the repos/ppa

```
ema@scv:~$ grep -h ^deb /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty main restricted
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates main restricted
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty universe
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates universe
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty multiverse
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates multiverse
deb http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://gb.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty-security multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu trusty partner
deb http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb-src http://extras.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/maarten-baert/simplescreenrecorder/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/maarten-baert/simplescreenrecorder/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/osmoma/audio-recorder/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/osmoma/audio-recorder/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/pipelight/stable/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-snapshots/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/stebbins/handbrake-snapshots/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/stefansundin/truecrypt/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/stefansundin/truecrypt/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/sunab/kdenlive-release/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/sunab/kdenlive-release/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-wine/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/xorg-edgers/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/xorg-edgers/ppa/ubuntu trusty main
```

Comment: Actually 14.04 should have linux kernel 13.6

Comment: @wyas that would be 14.04.2 (or the hardware stack for 14.10)

Comment: @Rinzwind ah yeah good point just read it https://wiki.ubuntu.com/TrustyTahr/ReleaseNotes

Comment: That should be working for you. Can you give us any more information? Does apt-get say something isn't right or that the kernel is already the most recent or whatever. Is there enough space on /boot to add another kernel?

Comment: @DougSmythies There is enough space on _/boot_ (128 GB, _/home_ is on another partition). How do I check with apt-get that I got the latest packages? Anyway, _apt-get update && upgrade && upgrade-dist_ doesn't report nothing... Added the list of repos/ppa in main question. Let me know what else.

Comment: Should I be installing _sudo apt-get install linux-image-3.13.0-46-generic_ manually?

Comment: I didn't know you had so much PPA stuff. I wonder if some dependency within a PPA is what is preventing apt-get from deciding to get and install a newer kernel. Forcing it as per your last comment might tell you if there is a dependency issue.

Comment: @DougSmythies So which command should I execute to check if dependencies are broken? What should I execute? _sudo apt-get install linux-generic_? Something else?

Comment: yes, sudo apt-get install linux-image-3.13.0-46-generic

Comment: @DougSmythies Yesterday I tried, then was late and _Ctrl+C_. But from the looks of it it didn't raise any complaint. Will this also install headers and re-compile all the kernel modules such nVidia proprietary drivers?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is apt no longer updating the kernel?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/175385/why-is-apt-no-longer-updating-the-kernel)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently I didn't have the meta package `linux-generic` installed... A simple

```
sudo apt-get install linux-generic && sudo apt-get install --reinstall nvidia-346
```

Did the trick!
Amazing, didn't think I somehow managed to remove that meta-package...

Now I got

```
ema@scv:~$ uname -a
Linux scv 3.13.0-46-generic #75-Ubuntu SMP Tue Feb 10 15:24:04 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Result!

Answer (score 0):

First run the `cat /etc/issue` command to verify what Ubuntu version do you have. I have the same kernel as you do, but my kernel Ubuntu version is 14.04. There is always a difference in between a kernel version and the distribution version.

Comment: I've got _Ubuntu 14.04.2 LTS_ apparently...

Comment: then goto `http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/` download the 3 or 4 debs. then install them using `dpkg -i packageName`. Reboot your system