# No fix to kernel that stopped updating on its own

Tags: kernel, updates, macbook, macbook-pro, versions

I finally created an account here !

I have a 2015 macbook pro running Ubuntu 16.04, with the kernel 4.4.0-72-generic. I have been using this computer on linux for about two years and I don't understand why I don't have kernel updates anymore.

I installed Ukuu and it tells me that the last version available is 4.14.4 ! Is this normal ? I used to have every.. two weeks ? a severall hundred MB update of the linux headers and image but now I don't get any of that for months.

I can't seem to understand since when or why this happens.

The command I use to look for update is :
`sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade && sudo apt clean`

When searching on this site I stumbled upon this : [Why is apt no longer updating the kernel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/175385/why-is-apt-no-longer-updating-the-kernel)

No of the proposed fix worked :

- `sudo apt-get install linux` returned `E: Unable to locate package linux`
- `sudo apt-get install linux-generic` returned `linux-generic is already the newest version (4.4.0.72.78).`
- `sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic` returned `linux-image-generic is already the newest version (4.4.0.72.78).`
- `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` returns `0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.`

I think it might have to do with this one time I used ukuu to install a recent kernel but everything crash so I think I ended up manually returning to the old one, but it was such a long time ago I'm not sure that was it.

Comment: Something is wrong with your system. The latest 4.4 kernel is `4.4.0.103.108`. Please post the output of `apt-cache policy linux-generic`.

Comment: It gives :
    `linux-generic:`
  `Installed: 4.4.0.72.78`
  `Candidate: 4.4.0.72.78`
  `Version table:`
 `*** 4.4.0.72.78 100`
        `100 /var/lib/dpkg/status`
     `4.4.0.21.22 500`
        `500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages`

Comment: It looks lile `xenial-updates` is not turned on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like `xenial-updates` and `xenial-security` are not turned on in "Software & Updates". Turn it on there. It should show

```
apt-cache policy linux-generic
linux-generic:
  Installed: 4.4.0.103.108
  Candidate: 4.4.0.103.108
  Version table:
 *** 4.4.0.103.108 500
        500 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     4.4.0.21.22 500
        500 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: That was it ! I now have about 1GB of update for the past months, enough to fill up my entire screen :p. Thank you very very very much ! I have no idea why I had seemingly disabled this. Good day to you !

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this before so maybe this will fix it for you.

First do

```
sudo apt-mark showmanual | grep linux-image
```

if you see an output something like (of course yours will be older ones not the new ones like I used in the example)

```
linux-image-4.4.0-101-generic
linux-image-4.4.0-103-generic
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-101-generic
linux-image-extra-4.4.0-103-generic
linux-image-generic
```

make note of these

Then do

```
 sudo apt-mark showmanual | grep linux-headers
```

if you see something like this

```
linux-headers-4.4.0-101
linux-headers-4.4.0-101-generic
linux-headers-4.4.0-103
linux-headers-4.4.0-103-generic
linux-headers-generic
```

make note of those

if this is the case .. that may be why they arent updating .. you will need to do

```
sudo apt-mark auto linux-image-4.4.0-101-generic linux-image-4.4.0-103-generic ...and so on for all the items
```

you want to have `sudo apt-mark auto` for any

```
linux-image-4.x.x-xxx-generic
linux-image-extra-4.x.x-xxx-generic
linux-image-generic
linux-headers-4.x.x-xxx
linux-headers-4.x.x-xxx-generic
linux-headers-generic
```

once those are all marked auto instead of manual

When you do the two commands

```
sudo apt-mark showmanual | grep linux-image
sudo apt-mark showmanual | grep linux-headers
```

and you got no output and you can check

```
sudo apt-mark showauto | grep linux-image
sudo apt-mark showauto | grep linux-headers
```

they should all show up in auto ... then do a

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

and they should show the latest and once installed it should show the older ones available for `sudo apt-get autoremove` (well  ... autoremove will not remove the newest and second newest in your list ..just in case you need to go back a step-- which is why mine shows two version still)

You should now get any new kernels when they become available

hope this helps

Warning: This is only the way to fix this .. don't make the mistake of thinking "oh this is great I'll just make everything auto and it will update everything and I can clean my system with `apt-get autoremove`"

If you do that .. your system will be hosed :D ... some things can not be set to auto and if they are .. autoremove will remove things the system needs to run.

I figured I better include this warning for those new who may make that mistake.

Comment: Very interesting thanks a lot. `sudo apt-mark showmanual` showed me that `linux-image-generic` and `linux-headers-generic` were set to manual, nothing else. I then put them in auto mode and tried to upgrade with `sudo apt-get upgrade` (after update of course) to no avail. I put them in manual afterwards because I'm not sure to fully understand your warning. Do you have another suggestion ?

Comment: no i would leave those two at auto. I guess i messed up a bit I will edit the answer .. both `linux-image-generic` and `linux-headers-generic` as well as the things i show in the example are auto on mine... when you do the `sudo apt-mark showauto | grep linux-image` do you see the `linux-image-4.x.x-xxx-generic` entries so they are already auto or dont you see any listed in auto or manual?

Comment: here is what I have listed when I do the two commands .. I posted a screen shot on [Imgur here](https://imgur.com/a/1QNZb)

Comment: Well my problem was fixed by another answer, but thank your for your dedication. To answer your question : after the fix the `linux-headers/image-generic` are both in manual now. I don't understand exactly of this works so I will leave it at that, given that my updates now work normally.

Comment: well like i say .. those two can be auto if you want .. they are normally auto .. and auto on my system .. but ..if its working .. i guess you are ok ... but keep an eye on it and remember this post so if it doesnt work next time there is a kernel update you can try making those auto again .. good luck :D .glad you got it working :D

Comment: Oh I didn't understand, well if they normally are in auto I'll put them in auto then :) thanks !