# Ubuntu 22.04 kernel won't upgrade

Tags: kernel, 22.04

We're currently using Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-153-generic x86_64) and trying to upgrade the kernel to 5.15 or newer. Still even after searching through several posts, wikis, etc, the kernel will stay on 5.4.0. We're out of ideas and hope that someone can point us to the right direction.

What we tried:

- `sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade && sudo apt clean && sudo apt autoremove` [based on this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/984902/no-fix-to-kernel-that-stopped-updating-on-its-own)
- `sudo apt-get install linux` returned `E: Unable to locate package linux`
- `sudo apt-get install linux-generic` returned `linux-generic is already the newest version (5.15.0.89.86)`
- `sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic` returned `linux-image-generic is already the newest version (5.15.0.89.86)`
- Using ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh based of the answer of [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1388115/how-do-i-update-my-kernel-to-the-latest-one). After testing we uninstalled the kernel via same script.
- `sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-22.04` [based on this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1393067/my-kernel-is-not-being-upgraded)

Still after reboot `uname -r` will return `5.4.0-153-generic`

From what I read in other posts you probably need these information (let me know if something is missing):

```
$ uname -a
Linux vm-server-1 5.4.0-153-generic #170-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 16 13:43:31 UTC 2023 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
$ sudo apt policy linux-image
linux-image:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: (none)
  Version table:
```

```
$ sudo apt-cache policy linux-generic
linux-generic:
  Installed: 5.15.0.89.86
  Candidate: 5.15.0.89.86
  Version table:
 *** 5.15.0.89.86 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.15.0.25.27 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu jammy/main amd64 Packages
```

```
$ sudo apt-mark showmanual | grep linux-image
linux-image-generic
```

```
$ sudo apt-mark showmanual | grep linux-headers
# nothing
```

```
$ sudo apt-mark showauto | grep linux-image
linux-image-5.15.0-89-generic
linux-image-6.2.0-37-generic
linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04
```

```
$ sudo apt-mark showauto | grep linux-headers
linux-headers-5.15.0-89
linux-headers-5.15.0-89-generic
linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic
linux-headers-generic
linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04
```

```
$ sudo update-grub
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-6.2.0-37-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-6.2.0-37-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.15.0-89-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.15.0-89-generic
Warning: os-prober will not be executed to detect other bootable partitions.
Systems on them will not be added to the GRUB boot configuration.
Check GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER documentation entry.
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings ...
done
```

```
$ sudo grub-editenv list
# nothing
```

```
$ sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep linux-image
linux-image-5.15.0-76-generic           deinstall
linux-image-5.15.0-78-generic           deinstall
linux-image-5.15.0-79-generic           deinstall
linux-image-5.15.0-82-generic           deinstall
linux-image-5.15.0-83-generic           deinstall
linux-image-5.15.0-84-generic           deinstall
linux-image-5.15.0-86-generic           deinstall
linux-image-5.15.0-87-generic           deinstall
linux-image-5.15.0-88-generic           deinstall
linux-image-5.15.0-89-generic           install
linux-image-6.2.0-37-generic            install
linux-image-generic             install
linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04           install
```

```
$ sudo dpkg -l | egrep linux-'[g|h|i|m]'
ii  binutils-x86-64-linux-gnu             2.38-4ubuntu2.3                         amd64        GNU binary utilities, for x86-64-linux-gnu target
ii  linux-generic                         5.15.0.89.86                            amd64        Complete Generic Linux kernel and headers
ii  linux-generic-hwe-22.04               6.2.0.37.38~22.04.15                    amd64        Complete Generic Linux kernel and headers
ii  linux-headers-5.15.0-89               5.15.0-89.99                            all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 5.15.0
ii  linux-headers-5.15.0-89-generic       5.15.0-89.99                            amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 5.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-6.2.0-37-generic        6.2.0-37.38~22.04.1                     amd64        Linux kernel headers for version 6.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-headers-generic                 5.15.0.89.86                            amd64        Generic Linux kernel headers
ii  linux-headers-generic-hwe-22.04       6.2.0.37.38~22.04.15                    amd64        Generic Linux kernel headers
ii  linux-hwe-6.2-headers-6.2.0-37        6.2.0-37.38~22.04.1                     all          Header files related to Linux kernel version 6.2.0
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-76-generic         5.15.0-76.83                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-78-generic         5.15.0-78.85                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-79-generic         5.15.0-79.86                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-82-generic         5.15.0-82.91                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-83-generic         5.15.0-83.92                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-84-generic         5.15.0-84.93                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-86-generic         5.15.0-86.96                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-87-generic         5.15.0-87.97                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
rc  linux-image-5.15.0-88-generic         5.15.0-88.98                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-5.15.0-89-generic         5.15.0-89.99                            amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-6.2.0-37-generic          6.2.0-37.38~22.04.1                     amd64        Signed kernel image generic
ii  linux-image-generic                   5.15.0.89.86                            amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
ii  linux-image-generic-hwe-22.04         6.2.0.37.38~22.04.15                    amd64        Generic Linux kernel image
rc  linux-modules-5.15.0-76-generic       5.15.0-76.83                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.15.0-78-generic       5.15.0-78.85                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.15.0-79-generic       5.15.0-79.86                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.15.0-82-generic       5.15.0-82.91                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.15.0-83-generic       5.15.0-83.92                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.15.0-84-generic       5.15.0-84.93                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.15.0-86-generic       5.15.0-86.96                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.15.0-87-generic       5.15.0-87.97                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-5.15.0-88-generic       5.15.0-88.98                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-5.15.0-89-generic       5.15.0-89.99                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-6.2.0-37-generic        6.2.0-37.38~22.04.1                     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 6.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-76-generic 5.15.0-76.83                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-78-generic 5.15.0-78.85                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-79-generic 5.15.0-79.86                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-82-generic 5.15.0-82.91                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-83-generic 5.15.0-83.92                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-84-generic 5.15.0-84.93                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-86-generic 5.15.0-86.96                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-87-generic 5.15.0-87.97                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
rc  linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-88-generic 5.15.0-88.98                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-extra-5.15.0-89-generic 5.15.0-89.99                            amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 5.15.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
ii  linux-modules-extra-6.2.0-37-generic  6.2.0-37.38~22.04.1                     amd64        Linux kernel extra modules for version 6.2.0 on 64 bit x86 SMP
```

```
$ ls /boot
System.map-5.15.0-89-generic  config-5.15.0-89-generic  grub        initrd.img-5.15.0-89-generic  initrd.img.old  vmlinuz                    vmlinuz-6.2.0-37-generic
System.map-6.2.0-37-generic   config-6.2.0-37-generic   initrd.img  initrd.img-6.2.0-37-generic   lost+found      vmlinuz-5.15.0-89-generic  vmlinuz.old
```

```
$ cat /etc/*release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=22.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=jammy
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS"
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS"
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION_ID="22.04"
VERSION="22.04.3 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)"
VERSION_CODENAME=jammy
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
UBUNTU_CODENAME=jammy
```

Partition information:

```
$ sudo parted -l
Model: ATA Samsung SSD 870 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 2000GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  2097kB  1049kB                     bios_grub
 2      2097kB  2150MB  2147MB  ext4
 3      2150MB  2000GB  1998GB


Model: Linux device-mapper (linear) (dm)
Disk /dev/mapper/ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv: 1998GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: loop
Disk Flags:

Number  Start  End     Size    File system  Flags
 1      0,00B  1998GB  1998GB  ext4


Model: Samsung SSD 960 EVO 500GB (nvme)
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags:

Number  Start   End     Size    File system  Name  Flags
 1      1049kB  538MB   537MB   fat32              boot, esp
 2      538MB   1612MB  1074MB  ext4
 3      1612MB  500GB   498GB


$ sudo lsblk -f
NAME                      FSTYPE      FSVER    LABEL UUID                                   FSAVAIL FSUSE% MOUNTPOINTS
loop0                     squashfs    4.0                                                         0   100% /snap/core20/1974
loop1                     squashfs    4.0                                                         0   100% /snap/core20/2015
loop2                     squashfs    4.0                                                         0   100% /snap/lxd/24322
loop3                     squashfs    4.0                                                         0   100% /snap/snapd/20092
loop4                     squashfs    4.0                                                         0   100% /snap/snapd/20290
sda
├─sda1
├─sda2                    ext4        1.0            a2c63d1f-fec5-4509-a3d6-5ad29a80659a      1,5G    14% /boot
└─sda3                    LVM2_member LVM2 001       ZfgXCe-fGAO-4892-UF2D-V4gq-d7hQ-5SggRI
  └─ubuntu--vg-ubuntu--lv ext4        1.0            6b157c55-6273-4694-bc9d-237cea92d8d8      1,7T     2% /
nvme0n1
├─nvme0n1p1               vfat        FAT32          4CEE-91B6
├─nvme0n1p2               ext4        1.0            f007e56e-a254-48ea-8468-c65ecc7b478e
└─nvme0n1p3

$ cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/ubuntu-vg/ubuntu-lv during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-id/dm-uuid-LVM-1OpWKw4SuxDrjnHjXbSxnsYuaTPZbHWZfd2iKx7srOOcU4DgSRcde81utmMRfYC1 / ext4 defaults 0 1
# /boot was on /dev/sda2 during curtin installation
/dev/disk/by-uuid/a2c63d1f-fec5-4509-a3d6-5ad29a80659a /boot ext4 defaults 0 1
/swap.img   none    swap    sw  0   0
```

Hardware:

- ASUS PRIME B350-PLUS Motherboard
- AMD Ryzen 7 1700 Eight-Core Processor

And still after reboot, `uname -r` will return `5.4.0-153-generic`. Final notes: When installing a new package via `apt install` there is a message that a new kernel has been found and will be used after reboot. But Kernel stays on 5.4.

Comment: Did you have a dualboot with another linux by any chance?

Comment: Please check which Kernels are listed in **/boot/grub/grub.cfg**? Make sure not to edit the file accidentality, just open for viewing using less or so.

Comment: Can you also add the output of `cat /etc/*release`?  The 5.4 Kernel was never in Ubuntu 22.04.  It started with 5.15.

Comment: @Terrance Added the output to my question. There was previously Ubuntu 20.04 installed, however my colleague said he did a clean Ubuntu 22.04 install.

Comment: @noisefloor I grepped for 5.4 in grub.cfg, no results. But I found two menu entries for 5.15.

Comment: @nobody There was previously Ubuntu 20.04 installed, however my colleague said he did a clean Ubuntu 22.04 install. Maybe you're right and there are some leftovers on another partition. Do you know how to check it?

Comment: @ts-mothership: please open a terminal, run `sudo update-grub` and add the output to your question.

Comment: @noisefloor is already part of the question.

Comment: Please open a terminal and type `dpkg --list | grep linux-image` to show all installed kernel versions – if installed correctly, note that the ones with ii in front are actually installed! The ones with rc are just leftover config files and can be purged.

Comment: @darth_epoxy Since those infos are already in the question, I formatted my question more, so the commands are better visible. I hope that helps :)

Comment: @ts-mothership: ok, thx. Overseen this. Based on the output you should see two options in the GRUB menu when booting, one for 6.2 and one for the 5.15 kernel.
In case you do not see the entries at boot, edit the file **/etc/default/grub** and make sure there is a generous timeout set and the menu is visible so you can manually select an entry as necessary.

Comment: Ok short update: it strongly looks like a partition issue. When changing boot sequence, Ubuntu will load Kernel 6.2. Seems there is another partition on same HDD.

Comment: `sudo parted -l` and `sudo lsblk -f` also `cat /etc/fstab` please.

Comment: @nobody added partition information to question

Comment: I see what goes on; but do not know how to repair it in a save way. The previous ubuntu/focal was in bios mode. The new jammy is in uefi mode in my opinion.. `1      1049kB  2097kB  1049kB                     bios_grub` this is a left over from focal.

Comment: @nobody thanks, that's probably it. We can boot Ubuntu from another partition, then the 6.2 Kernel is selected. We're currently discussing if we're just reinstall with new partitions. If you want, add your comments as answer, then I'll mark your answer as solution.

Comment: A new install is not a solution. And maybe another one who has much more experience in uefi stuff than me can help with a solution. as a workaround I would set in uefi the EVO drive as 1. bootdevice. And please decide for one kerneltree.

Answer (score 1):

Since we completely reinstalled the server, no answers are needed anymore.

Most likely Ubuntu 22.04 wasn't correctly installed before, an old linux kernel from another partition was chosen in boot instead of the newer, installed kernel.